# What properties of atoms can be derived to high accuracy from a theory of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I'm trying to understand which predictions some of the theories of quantum mechanics can make.

This is the picture I estimate in my layman's attempt:

- the fundamental properties of particles can be derived to high accuracy by quantum field theory
- the situation is much more dissatisfying for the fundamental properties of atoms (mass, electronegativity, etc.)
- for molecules, there may be some semi-accurate result for a specific one here and there (boiling point for water would be awesome)

If that's correct in broad strokes, it would leave mostly the atomic layer for me to learn about what can be predicted there.

I'd love to hear about what properties of whole atoms can be derived from first principles of a quantum theory.

Comment: You may also want to see [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "what properties of whole atoms can be derived from first principles of a quantum theory."  "derive" is a wrong word,  the word is "modeled" , physics theories model and predict data.

Comment: The hydrogen atom is practically fully modeled by QM. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the properties of fundamental particles (their mass, charge and strength of interactions with the weak and strong forces) are *not* predicted by quantum mechanics. Instead they are measured by experiment, and they are then used as inputs to the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. One of the unsolved questions in physics is why these masses and coupling constants take the values that they do, and whether these values are constrained in any way.

Once the properties of the fundamental particles are known, the behaviour of any system composed of those particles can *in principle* be understood by setting up and solving the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) for that system to find its wave function. However, in practice an exact solution of the Schrödinger equation can only be found for the very simplest systems.

The Schrödinger equation can be solved exactly for one electron orbiting one proton to give the possible orbital states of the electron in a hydrogen atom. For other atoms apart from hydrogen, approximate solutions have to be used, although these do give very accurate predictions for the behaviour of actual electrons in these atoms.

The [structure of the atomic nucelus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_structure) is less well understood, and the state of the art here relies on various ad-hoc and semi-classical models such as the [nuclear shell model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model).

Modelling the behaviour of molecules from first principles is even less advanced, and [molecular modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_modelling) relies on a combination of ad-hoc models such as the the [Leonard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) and computer simulations.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, I'd like to add that computational/quantum chemistry has a little bit more to offer than force fields and the Leonard-Jones potential when it comes to modeling molecules. Like the simple Hartree-Fock method to Domain Based local Pair Natural Orbital Coupled Cluster (DLPNO-CCSD(T)) method. Or perhaps you favor second-order multiconfigurational quasi-degenerate perturbation theory (MC-XQDPT2) ? I should probably also mention Density Functinonal Theory and Configuration Interaction. But the range of methods has grown beyond the size that could fit in a short comment.